# Color of webkit calendar

Tags: css, webkit

I would like to change the color of the calendar icon (input type="date") into green.
I try

```
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
 color: green
}
```

But it doesn't work, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try it any of them.

```
selector {
    background-color: green;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the background in green but the color of the icon

Comment: May I have the icon or website link, please?

Comment: it's the icon when you add an <input type="date">